# XGrabpointer + autohotkeyX_master combo for gaming in Linux

Tags: tinycore

I have an old desktop P4 with Hyper Threading Technology, 1Gig RAM, 256 Nvidia 5500FX AGP and I am new to Linux OS, Tiny Core Linux 4.0 is the flavor I use.

I was curious about possibility of playing an online game (Dota Frozen Throne) that is native to windows because it is in .exe format. I learned how to use wine (wine-1.4.1) as Transport layer interface of windows programs in Linux. I already successfully compiled and installed my AGP driver (NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39).

The problem is game is crashing every time I execute it with wine. So I search for solutions. I found a remedy that is executing it in window mode

WINEDEBUG=-all wine explorer /desktop=foo,1280x720 "/home/tc/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Warcraft III/Frozen Throne.exe" -window -opengl

Now I can play it without crashing. But the problem is I need two more things to make my game well played.

First I need a auto-hotkey that will use keyboard shortcuts instead of manual clicking some gui-controls. Though I have already autohotkey in .exe it's not working that way because in window explorer mode of WINE only one instance is active even I have multiple instance inside it. The only option is to make from scratch a global auto-hotkey that will be run in linux system by installing this, but I do not know how to... https://codeload.github.com/tinku99/ahkx/zip/master

Quote

```
/*
AutoHotkeyX

Copyright 2003-2009 Naveen Garg (naveen.garg@gmail.com)

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.
*/
dependencies: xdotool, wine-dev, libx11-dev, libxt-dev
also see debian/control


./build
./run scriptname
```

The second thing I need, because I'm in window mode and my cursor tends to slip outside the game window is a cursor lock app, again I have that ( Cursor_Lock_2.6.1, WMC_1.2.3) but It's not working in wine even I installed mono or .NET 2.0.  The only option I have is this http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/XGrabPointer.3.html#toc But I really do not know where to encode it and I'm confused about it's variables, I don't know what to fill. Thanks